# What happens if I assign a number with a decimal point to an integer rather than to a float?

Tags: c++

A friend of mine asked me this question earlier, but I found myself clutching at straws trying to give him an adequate explanation.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @Beta Why does trying it help? If it is UB then trying it gets you nowhere.

Comment: Is it just me, or is the fact that you can happily assign a float to an int not utterly depressing.

Comment: I didn't need to try it, as I already understand what happens. I simply couldn't think of how to word it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign a value of any numeric type (integer, floating-point) to an object of another numeric type, the value is implicitly *converted* to the target type.  The same thing happens in an initialization or when passing an argument to a function.

The rules for how the conversion is done vary with what kind of types you're using.

If the target type can represent the value exactly:

```
short s = 42;
int i = s;

double x = 42.0;
int j = x;
```

there may be a change in representation, but the mathematical value is unchanged.

If a floating-point type is converted to an integer type, and the value *can't* be represented, it's truncated, as @sashang's answer says -- but if the truncated value can't be represented, the behavior is undefined.

Conversion of an integer (either signed or unsigned) to an *unsigned* type causes the value to be reduced modulo `MAX+1`, where `MAX` is the maximum value of the unsigned type.  For example:

```
unsigned short s = 70000; // sets s to 4464 (70000 - 65536)
                          // if unsigned short is 16 bits
```

Conversion of an integer to a *signed* type, if the value won't fit, is implementation-defined.  It typically wraps around in a manner similar to what happens with unsigned types, but the language doesn't guarantee that.

Answer (score 4):

A float or a double will be truncated. So 2.99 will become 2 and -2.99 will become -2.

The pertinent section from the standard (section 4.9)

> 1 A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of
>   an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional
>   part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value
>   cannot be represented in the destination type.

Comment: You should show the negative case as well as it might be counter-intuitive.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I used a floundering rounding down analogy, but only achieved a barrage of questions from him. ("Why not up then? ... etc) Actually using truncated will make it clearer for him.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It's undefined if the *truncated value* can't be represented in the destination type.

Comment: OK, I get it. Sorry! All the same, example with negative values would be interesting.

Comment: Funny. Ideone truncates -2.99 to 254 using gcc 4.3.4. Go figure. http://ideone.com/oLDzA

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That's probably because of the way the shell interprets the return value from that program. -2 becomes 254.

Comment: "if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type." What does that mean?